# Using csv I want to select an random row with data and extract the data so S =songs and A = artist,repeat

Tags: python, export-to-csv, python-re

My attempt bellow, can you help improve it, thanks in advance.

```
def Start():
    with open('Songs.csv') as Data #Call file
    Read = csv.reader(Data,delimiter=':', quotechar='|')#return tuple of songs and artists
    for row in Read :
        X = random.choice(row)#random selection
        Store = (','.join(X))#(Song,Artist)
        A = re.compile(‘,’)
        for s in finditer(Store):
            POS = s.start()#positional arg for slicing
            global Song
            Song = X[POS:]#song,
            global Artist
            Artist = X[:POS]#Artist
            print(Song)
```

Comment: Your example contains syntax errors. It can't possibly be the code you're running.

Comment: Please move the text in the question to the post itself, and keep the question as short and clear heading.

Comment: Please, send an example of what is in Songs.csv

Comment: AKX this is a raw untested expression of my problem so i have not yet gotten to testing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the heading i suppose you want to read a file line by line and split the line based on a delimiter. The following code can be helpful

```
def Start():
with open('Songs.csv') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    columns = line.split(':')
    #read columns list using index to get any values
```

The code you provided isn't much helpful. I suggest to a description with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Pls. correct me, if I do not understand the question in a right way, but I think it would mush easier to read this csv file with pandas.

like:

```py
import pandas as pd

songs = pd.read_csv("Songs.csv", header=False, sep =",")
```

Then the first col in your dataframe would be the Song and the second one is the artist.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I guessed the question ;-)? This prints all songs and artists in random order (shuffled song list):

```
import re, csv, random

def Start():
    with open('new.csv') as Data:
        Read = csv.reader(Data,delimiter=':', quotechar='|')
        l = [line for line in Read]
        print(l)
        for _ in range(len(l)):                 # whatever length
            song, artist = random.choice(l)
            print(song, artist)
            l.remove([song, artist])

Start()
```